Unexpected QT application Crash without error
I have a function into which I am passing 3072x64 32 bit raw data doing it 82 times in half second.
This whole 3072X64X82 is one big picture processed and displayed every second.
Now processing this raw data and then creating a pixmap and updating each pixles in a chunk of 3072X64
Everything works great when I capture less then 69 such (3072X64X82) huge images no lag nothing but as soon as i hit 69 application unexpectedly crashes.
In this line when I comment *pixel = scaledPixelValue; this line then it works it doesn't give me any memory error or out of bound error.
I tried to print to debug but still no debug print and still application crashes.
I have tested by sending 16 bit data rather then 32 and then the application crashes exactly at 140th  (3072X64X82).
Here is the sudo code
Things to Note unit8_t is the address in the memory, recv_frames is the offset in the memory.
void Display::ProcessRecievedFrame(bool ifComplete, uint8_t* images, int recv_frames) {

int width = 3072;
int frameHeight = 64;
int totalLines = 5248;
int scalefactor = 15;

if (currentLine >= totalLines) {
    qWarning("All lines have been processed");
    return;
}

const uint16_t* rawPixels = reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(images);

// Calculate the size of the rawPixels data buffer
size_t rawPixelsSize = width * frameHeight * 2 * recv_frames;  // or adjust based on actual buffer size

for (int y = 0; y < frameHeight; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        unsigned long long bufIndex = (y * width * 2 + x * 2) + ((recv_frames - 1) * width * 2 * frameHeight);

        // Check if bufIndex is within bounds
        if (bufIndex < 0 || bufIndex >= rawPixelsSize) {
            qWarning() << "bufIndex out of bounds:" << bufIndex << "rawPixelsSize:" << rawPixelsSize;
            return;
            continue;
        }

        ushort pixelValue = rawPixels[bufIndex];
        uint16_t* pixel = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(image.scanLine(y + currentLine)) + x;

        // Check if the scanLine pointer is valid
        if (y + currentLine >= image.height()) {
            qWarning() << "Invalid y + currentLine:" << y + currentLine;
            continue;
        }

        // Cast the pixelValue to a double before calling std::isfinite
        if (std::isfinite(static_cast<double>(pixelValue)) && pixelValue >= 0) {
            int scaledPixelValue = static_cast<int>((pixelValue - 0) * scalefactor + 0.5);

            // Ensure scaledPixelValue stays within a reasonable range
            scaledPixelValue = qBound(0, scaledPixelValue, 65535);

            // Check for possible issues before assignment
            if (scaledPixelValue >= 0 && scaledPixelValue <= 65535) {
                if (scaledPixelValue) {
                    *pixel = scaledPixelValue;
                }
            } else {
                // Log or handle the case where scaledPixelValue is out of range
                qDebug() << "scaledPixelValue is out of expected bounds:" << scaledPixelValue;
            }
        } else {
            // Log or handle invalid pixelValue
            qDebug() << "Invalid pixelValue:" << pixelValue;
        }

    }
}

currentLine += frameHeight;

emit frameProcessed(image);

if (ifComplete) {
    delete[] images;
    return;
}

if (currentLine > 5244) {
    qDebug() << "image reset" << currentLine;
    currentLine = 0;
    image = QImage();
    image = QImage(3072, 5248, QImage::Format_Grayscale16);
}

}

You are probably running out of memory. And what may happen then is that some exception/fault occurs, and some code tries to handle that exception, but it lacks memory to do it, and then the app just gives up.

Side note: You praise whatever deities you worship when you can get an error message before a crash.

@Dialecticus I thought of the same but I have 64GB memory and I have tracked the memory and it crashed even when my total consumption is roughly 5 GB. And like I have mentioned if I comment that particular line then even though my memory goes to 12GB when it was capturing more pictures but still my application doesn't crash.

@user4581301 That's the problem I didn't get any error message or code my application just crash. Please help!

All I'm saying is you almost never get an error message. What I would do right now is  turn on the address sanitizer (ASAN) and see if it can catch the problem. If your tools don't support ASAN, load the program into whatever debugger comes with your tools. Put a breakpoint on the function you've shown us, and set the breakpoint to skip the first 68 times it's called. Step through the 69th and take good notes. A debugger usually halts when the program crashes so you can inspect the crash site; see if you can make sense of the backtrace.

Also pay careful attention to uint16_t* pixel = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(image.scanLine(y + currentLine)) + x;. If commenting out *pixel = scaledPixelValue; hides the problem by making it survivable, odds are very good that pixel is pointing somewhere nasty.

If you are still stuck, use the information you've gathered to build a [mre] and update the question with something we can run and watch fail.

The only proper way to help you is to have the code that we can compile, run, and see the issue with our own eyes. This code is not enough, so we can't really-really hep you. We can only guess.

In Windows project I had a similar problem. An assert is triggered, and assert wants to show a message box, but then another Windows message is processed that causes another assert. CRT can't handle double-assert and calls exit. This is program just giving up. Put a breakpoint in assert function to catch first assert while you debug. Or stop execution on first exception, while you debug.

You didn't say what's your OS. In Windows you see if there's some useful info in Event Viewer.
